# How to create a Shapely LineString from two arrays of points

Tags: python, python-2.7, shapely

I am trying to create a single LineString object of two arrays. I've tried this a multiple of ways, but I keep getting :

```
>>> array = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)][(1,3),(1.4,2),(2,0)]
```

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

```
##      A
##       \
##        \
##         X
##          \
##           \
## B-----C-----D-----F

## Test to Identify Junctions - Shared points where two or more lines intersect

def test_find_junctions(self):
    g = PreserveTopology()
    # LINE BCDF, AXD
    array = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)][(1,3),(1.4,2),(2,0)]
    # LINE AXD
    #array2 = [(1,3),(1.4,2),(2,0)]
    array_as_linestring = LineString(array)
    #array2_as_linestring = LineString(array2)
    result = g.find_junctions_line(array_as_linestring)
    assert_equal(result,(2,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enclose your list in square brackets, if you want it to be an array, and then separate the lists with commas.

```
array = [[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)],[(1,3),(1.4,2),(2,0)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two line segments, so you need to either have a list of LineString geometries, or a MultiLineString geometry. Continuing with the Syntax error fix by @David, you can build either of these structures:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

array = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)], [(1, 3), (1.4, 2), (2, 0)]]

ls = [LineString(ar) for ar in array]
mls = MultiLineString(array)
```

Comment: definitely don't want a MultiLinestring...but the LineString + syntax fix was the winner. Thanks.